# Como elaborar uma Calculadora simples com JavaScript puro?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Bom pessoal sou iniciante na área de web e JavaScript. Meu professor me pediu para elaborar uma Calculadora simples com as quatro operações (+), (-), (*), (/). Somente com o Javascript puro para rodar no terminal, sem códigos HTML ou demais.
Então vi que tem a necessidade de se criar as perguntas sobre qual operação o usuário deseja efetuar, assim como digitar o primeiro e o segundo número. Utilizei o IF/Else, consegui até rodar o código, mas na hora de mostrar o resultado ele retorna NaN. Alguém poderia ajudar?
Esse é o código:

```
var valor
var valor1
var oper
var readlineSync = require('readline-sync');
oper = parseFloat(readlineSync.question("Qual operacao deseja efetuar (+) (-) (*) (/)? : \n"));
valor = parseFloat(readlineSync.question("Insira o primeiro numero: \n"));
valor1 = parseFloat(readlineSync.question("Insira o segundo numero: \n"));
   if (oper =="+") {
      return valor + valor1;
} else if 
      (oper == "-") {
      return valor - valor1;
   } else if
       (oper == "*") {
         return valor * valor1;
      } else if 
         (oper == "/") {
        return valor / valor1;
      } else {
      console.log('Não foi possível calcular')
      }
      console.log('O resultado é', +oper)
```

Comment: Ronde, você está usando `parseFloat` para receber o valor em `oper`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu código há algumas coisas para ajustar. Primeiro você está passando um float para a variável `oper` e outro ponto é que você está usando return, mas você não está no dentro de uma função.

Fiz um exemplo usando função para que você possa usar boa parte do seu código e fazer só alguns ajustes.

Espero que ajude.

```js
var valor
var valor1
var oper
var readlineSync = require('readline-sync');
oper = readlineSync.question("Qual operacao deseja efetuar (+) (-) (*) (/)? : \n");
valor = parseFloat(readlineSync.question("Insira o primeiro numero: \n"));
valor1 = parseFloat(readlineSync.question("Insira o segundo numero: \n"));

function doOperation(operator, value1, value2) {
    if (operator == "+") {
        return value1 + value2;
    } else if
        (operator == "-") {
        return value1 - value2;
    } else if
        (operator == "*") {
        return value1 * value2;
    } else if
        (operator == "/") {
        return value1 / value2;
    } else {
        throw new Error('Operação inválida');
    }
}


console.log('O resultado é', doOperation(oper, valor, valor1))
```

Coloquei dentro de uma função o código de verificação. Ela sempre retorna o valor de acordo com a operação, caso a operação não esteja especificada, lança um Erro.

Comment: Valeu, amigo me ajudou demais. Era exatamente isto que eu precisava fazer!

Answer (score -2):

Limpar
         
         
      
      
         
            7
         
         
            8
         
         
            9
         
         
            /
         
      
      
         
            6
         
         
            5
         
         
            4
         
         
            X
         
      
      
         
            3
         
         
            2
         
         
            1
         
         
            -

```
  </div>
  <div class="row pb-2">
     <div class="col-md-3">
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg btn-block'>0</button>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg btn-block'>,</button>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg btn-block'>=</button>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg btn-block'>+</button>
     </div>
  </div>
```

$(document).ready(function(){

         var valor1 = 0;
         var valor2 = 0;
         var oper = '';
         var resultado = 0;

         $('button').click(function(){

            $this = $(this);

            $('#resultado').val($('#resultado').val()+$this.html());

            if(checkchar(checklast($('#resultado').val()) ) === 'operator'){

               valor1 = $('#resultado').val().split(checklast($('#resultado').val()))[0];

               oper = checklast($('#resultado').val());

               $('#resultado').val('');
            }

            if(checkchar(checklast($('#resultado').val()) ) === 'equal'){

               valor2 =  $('#resultado').val()/*.split(oper)[1];*/

              switch(oper){
                  case 'X': resultado = parseFloat(valor1)*parseFloat(valor2);break;
                  case '/': resultado = parseFloat(valor1)/parseFloat(valor2);break;
                  case '+': resultado = parseFloat(valor1)+parseFloat(valor2);break;
                  case '-': resultado = parseFloat(valor1)-parseFloat(valor2);break;
              }

              $('#resultado').val(resultado)

            }
         })
      })

      function checklast(valor){
         return valor.substr(valor.length-1,valor.length);
      }

      function checkchar(character){

         var number = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
         var operator = ['X', '/', '-', '+'];


         // Verifica se é um número
         for(i in number){

            if(character.length>1){
               // cada caractere do 'character'
               for(l in character.length){
                  if(character[l] === number[i]){
                     return 'number'
                  }
               }
            }else{

            if(character === number[i]){
                  return 'number'
               }
            }
           
         }

         // Verifica se é um operador
         for(o in operator){
            if(character === operator[o]){
               return 'operator'
            }
         }
         
         // verficiar se é o sinal de igual
         if(character === '='){
            return 'equal';
         }


         // Verifica se é a virgula (separador)
         if(character === ','){
            return '.';
         }
      }

Comment: Formate sua resposta.